# If hermaphrodite C. elegans can reproduce with females?

Tags: genetics, reproduction, species

C. elegans can self fertilize, or they can mate with males. But are they able to mate with females? Or is there some kind of morphological barrier that prevents that?

Comment: By "females" you probably mean hermaphrodites: C. elegans have no females.

Comment: There are female mutants, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since only the male tail is equipped with various specialized sensory and copulatory structures that enable him to locate the vulva and successfully inseminate the hermaphrodite.  Hermaphrodites can self-fertilize, but only males can cross-fertilize a hermaphrodite.

sources: [Wormbook: Male development](http://www.wormbook.org/chapters/www_maledevelopment/maledevelopment.html)
[C. elegans II (2nd edition): Sexual Dimorphism](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK20094/)

Comment: The C elegans hermaphrodite is basically a female, except that she makes some sperm of her own. (Judith Kimble likes to say that a hermaphrodite is a female who's learned to be independent.) C elegans is derived from male/female species by a small change in sex determination in the female germ line. As you'd expect for a female, she can mate with males, but not other females.